# Eslint identifying cypress.io describe, it, and cy methods as "not defined"

Tags: vuejs3, cypress, eslint, vite

I have a vite/vue3 project which will use cypress.io as e2e testing. I recently went through a dependabot project update as a result of its findings.  Now my describe, it, and cy methods within cypress testing files are not recognized by eslint and 'appropriately' flagged. See my snapshot of vite-vue_standardSetup_eslintworkingincorrectly.  I initiated a brand new vite/vue3 project in new base folder. The cypress test file is not being flagged as 'not recognized'. See snapshot vite-vue_standardSetup_eslintworkingcorrectly. Only difference I can find is that eslint itself was upgraded to 8.56 from 8.49. I cannot find anything where this has been reported as an issue.  Any suggestions on how to correct this keyword flagging?

[image: Incorrectly Flagged cypress methods]

[image: No problems in cypress file]

[image: eslintrc file contents]

Comment: Please give a [mre] **as text**.

Comment: .eslintrc? Do you have plugin added there?

Comment: @szogoon, yes.  I have even tried moving the plugin:cypress/recommended statement out of the overrides section and into the root extends section then restarting VSCode. That did not change anything with my red squiggles in the cypress spec file.

I have even copied the eslintrc contents from vite/vue3's file and into the eslintrc file within my project. Didnt help either. Both projects are using the same version of the plugin for eslint's cypress (2.15.1).

Comment: @szogoon  I moved the whole project out of my WSL (Debian 11) guest and onto a folder in Windows 11 host.  npm install. Open new folder's project in VS Code, and no red squiggles. Something is amiss in my Debian system. Or a communication error with VSCode.

Comment: A bit of guessing - maybe it was caused by the eslint being installed via apt, and not by npm?

Comment: @szogoon I found it. Weirdness in VS Code with ESLint plugin. I found it odd that an "npm run lint" would not trigger any displayed errors in the console. But visually, I had red squiggles in *.cy.js files.  Uninstalled eslint plugin for VSCode, exited VSCode, relaunched VSCode.  Verified that all editor errors were gone visually. Then reinstalled eslint for VSCode.  My red squiggles are still gone even after exiting and relaunching VSCode two more times. Thank you for the oversight you have provided.